# Add date in php gives different results

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have to get a date which is 6 months added with specific date.
I used the following code

```
$start_date = "2016-08-30";
$end_date= date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "$start_date +6 months" ) );
echo $end_date;
```

which gave result as 2017-03-02

Then I changed the start date in code as below

```
$start_date = "2016-09-01";
$end_date= date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "$start_date +6 months" ) );
echo $end_date;
```

which is giving result as 2017-03-01

Why is this happening at first place? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Using Mysql query

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2016-08-30', INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

gives result 2017-02-28

Which is the right solution to get the correct date?

Comment: You can try this. $date = new DateTime('2016-08-30); $date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString(+6 months)); var_dump($date);

Comment: The correct question is: what do **you** mean by `2016-08-30 +6 months`? What date do you expect to get from this expression without using computers? Is it the 30th of the 6th month in the future (February in this case)? Or `2016-08-30` plus `6 * 30 days`?

Comment: @axiac: am also confused right now about expected output. I am using this functionality to expire a feature in my website. I shared this issue since an anomaly is found and may be helpful for others too.

Comment: @M. I. Did that too generate same results as mine?

Comment: Use days instead of months and your problem vanishes.

Comment: @Thejas yes. It should work ok, use DateTime object, and ->add(), date interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens  due to PHP's behavior. In this case  6 months are added which gives february(it has 28 days) so it adds three more days , but in MySQL it adds only months.

To solve this use `last day of 6 month` or `last day of sixth month` instead of `+6 months`

**Code**

```
$date = new DateTime( '2016-08-30' );
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d' ), "\n";
$date->modify( 'last day of sixth month' );
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d' ), "\n";
```

[Code Demo](https://3v4l.org/19Wmb)

**Output**

```
2016-08-30
2017-02-28
```

Another Solution

```
$date = new DateTime( '2016-08-25' );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'),"\n";
$day = $date->format('j');
$date->modify('first day of sixth month');
$date->modify('+' . (min($day, $date->format('t')) - 1) . ' days');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Code Demo](https://3v4l.org/NMVXL)

**Output**

```
2016-08-25
2017-02-25
```

Also refer [Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Answer (score 0):

This function DOES NOT work from left-to-right as one would think. This function parses the string as a whole, then applies the intervals by size (year, month, ...). Take the following example:

```
<?php
$Date = strtotime('2011-02-22'); // February 22nd, 2011. 28 days in this month, 29 next year.
echo date('n/j/Y', strtotime('+1 year, +7 days', $Date)); // add 1 year and 7 days. prints 2/29/2012
echo "<br />";
echo date('n/j/Y', strtotime('+7 days, +1 year', $Date)); // add 7 days and 1 year, but this also prints 2/29/2012
echo "<br />";
echo date('n/j/Y', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime('+7 days', $Date))); // this prints 3/1/2012, what the 2nd would do if it was left-to-right
?>
```